# Replace all spaces in a search input box with & character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I have a search input box on a site.
If the user enters text in the input box I like to replace all [space]-characters with ' & ' (in words: space&space)

But I have a small mistake in my code because if the user tries to delete text (backspace) then it inserts a ' & ' again if the last char was a replaced space...

See my example on JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/JFEb4/

Any ideas?

Code:

```
$("[name='search']").keyup(function() {

    var input = $(this).val().replace(/ & /g, "x");

    if (input.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
        $(this).val(input.replace(' ', ' & ').replace(/x/g, " & "

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to check if the spacebar was pressed before the characters are added to the value, and if it was, prevent the character from outputting and add `&` instead.
That would also avoid the backspace issue all together :

```
$("[name='search']").on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.value = this.value + ' & ';
    } 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JFEb4/2/)

Comment: not really, because if you try to enter some text in front then it will be pasted at the end, and also if you insert something from the clipboard then it will not work... Any more ideas?

Comment: Wow, many thanks adeneo! Only one small mistake, if a user paste some text that already contains ' & ' (Example: Test1 & Test2) then it will be replaced to '_$_' and I couldn´t find out why... Because I think it should be replaced from the second replace in the past function or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```
$("[name='search']")
    .on('keyup paste', function(e) {

        var replaceSpaces = function(el) {
            return function() {
                $(el).val($(el).val().replace(/(^|[^&])\s+($|[^&])/g, '$1 & $2'));
            };
        } (this);

        if (e.type === 'keyup' && e.which === 32) {
            replaceSpaces();
        } else if (e.type === 'paste') {
            setTimeout(replaceSpaces, 5);                
        }

    });
```

[(this code on jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/LgSNR/)